# Select first occurence from SQL Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This query

```sql
select  AM.Id, convert(int,sub.Version) as SubVersion , RP.Id as RPId 
from sub 
left join ZRP as RP on RP.sid=sub.id
left join ZAM as AM on AM.Id=RP.AmId
where SUB.Name='xxxx' and AmId<>''
order by  AM.Id, SubVersion
```

Returns the following result

| Id | SubVersion | RPId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **8a288b2976f5afd50176f5eeed941237** | **4** | ***8a288b2976f5afd50176f5eeedba123c*** |
| 8a288b2976f5afd50176f5eeed941237 | 5 | 8a28a00576f5afc70176f78489f30c75 |
| 8a288b2976f5afd50176f5eeed941237 | 6 | 8a28f1aa76f5c78c0176f7848f6e583e |
| **8a28a00576f5afc70176f78489a20c68** | **5** | ***8a28a00576f5afc70176f78489c20c6d*** |
| 8a28a00576f5afc70176f78489a20c68 | 6 | 8a28f1aa76f5c78c0176f7848f685836 |
| **8a28f1aa76f5c78c0176f7848ee2582a** | **6** | ***8a28f1aa76f5c78c0176f7848f1a582f*** |

I need to select RPId in Italic from the line in bolds, ie the first occurence of each Id value,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method (which is not the fastest) but doesn't require subqueries is to use a `with ties` trick:

```
select top (1) with ties AM.Id, convert(int,sub.Version) as SubVersion, RP.Id as RPId 
from sub left join
     ZRP RP
     on RP.sid = sub.id left join
     ZRP AM
     on AM.Id = RP.AmId
where SUB.Name = 'xxxx' and AmId <> ''
order by row_number() over (partition by AM.Id order by convert(int, SubVersion));
```

It seems odd that you are using `left join` and then focusing on columns from the last table.  I suspect that `inner join` might be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: inner join are sufficient indeed. Small mistakes  `ZAM AM` and `partition by AM.Id order by convert(int, sub.Version)`

Comment: @MilleBii . . . You are welcome to edit the answer.  However, these components are taken from the query in the question.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to go about solving this is to use a PARTITION.
https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-partition-by/

The partition acts like a group by and will group each sequence of id's. The sequence is reset when a new id is found. ROW_NUMBER() acts as a counter so the first one in the sequence will be marked as 1,2,3 and so on. When you take the final result you will look for a RowNumber=1 to only return the first result found for each grouping. The group order is determined by the ORDER BY statement in the partition.

```
WITH tempsub AS(
    select  AM.Id
    , convert(int,sub.Version) as SubVersion
    , RP.Id as RPId 
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AM.Id ORDER BY SubVers ASC) AS RowNumber
    from sub 
    left join ZRP as RP on RP.sid=sub.id
    left join ZRP as AM on AM.Id=RP.AmId
    where SUB.Name='xxxx' and AmId<>''
)
SELECT *
FROM tempsub
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```